# How do I do lchown in java, which is to work across all Unix flavors: Linux, redhat,hp-ux,rhel-5 and Solaris

Tags: java

I have filepath , userId and groupId, how do I do a lchown in java(for symlinks) which will work across all unix flavors:Linux, redhat,hp-ux,rhel-5 and Solaris

I tried exploring the java.nio.file package but could not spot the function which will help me achieve this.

This is golang equivalent:
os.Lchown(filePath,uid,gid)  -- How to achieve this in java?

Comment: maybe you could run it as as shell command: https://www.baeldung.com/run-shell-command-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at these :

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/FileOwnerAttributeView.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/PosixFilePermissions.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/PosixFileAttributes.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/GroupPrincipal.html

You can then do these kind of things :

```
Path path = Paths.get("/home/toto/myfile.zip");
FileOwnerAttributeView foav = Files.getFileAttributeView(path,
      FileOwnerAttributeView.class);

FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();
UserPrincipalLookupService upls = fs.getUserPrincipalLookupService();

//UserPrincipal new_user = upls.lookupPrincipalByName("brice");     
UserPrincipal new_user = upls.lookupPrincipalByName("1005");
foav.setOwner(new_user);

GroupPrincipal new_group = upls.lookupPrincipalByGroupName("everyone");
Files.getFileAttributeView(path, PosixFileAttributeView.class, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS).setGroup(new_group);
```

Comment: Is brice the userId I want to set?

Comment: that's it, well... maybe yours is not called 'brice' :)

Comment: Thanks a ton, I have 2 qs : 1.Will this work for symlinks?
2.I have to do the same thing for groups using group principal, isnt there an efficient way for this one That we can combine both of these?

Comment: Seems to work :) If answer was usefull, could you accept it, so others will find their info if needed

Comment: I added group change in the answer too

Comment: Sure, let me try it out :) The problem is I have userId and not username, lookupPrincipalByName needs a string

Comment: In fact it's easy : just replace 'brice' by the user id :)

Comment: @SamayraGoyal :  don't forget to accept the answer for further references : https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers